# Wordpress Directory Switch Issues

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I recently set up a digitalocean account with wordpress pre-installed. When it is pre-installed, the directory structure begins in the root (var/www/html/). I wanted to change this, so i moved the files into a new directory (/var/www/html/viralnewz) and changed the wp-config files to represent this (they no longer point to the http://178.62.87.202/ but instead to viralnewz.co.uk, which in turn will point to viral newz directory (/var/www/html/viralnewz). This is set up with a virtualhost, and works fine for the front-page and the admin. But when i try and view others pages, i get a 404 not found. I'm assuming theres an issue with the wordpress setup because it can't find the correct page, however i'm unclear how to actually solve this issue.

Apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/viralNewz/
ServerName viralnewz.co.uk

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Additionals to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://viralnewz.co.uk/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://viralnewz.co.uk/');
```

If i've missed any other information that could be beneficial, please mention it and i'll do my best to find it.

Chris

Comment: Did you try refreshing permalinks ?

Comment: If i change the permalinks back to plain, they work apart from images (need to change that with a plugin), but is there any way i could keep the same permalink structure as before?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be related to url values stored in DB. 
You can migrate safely using [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), that permit to find and replace the urls stored in DB.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Can be also necessary update .htacess file: normally is enough enter in permalink settings and save again the structure of permalinks.